# Cleanest way to maintain Views' paths

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, global-variables, modern-ui

I use [Modern UI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) in my project. Unfortunately, its navigation mechanics are based on absolute (or relative to project directory) paths to views' xaml files.

**Example window xaml**

```
...
<mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Menu">
    <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    <mui:Link DisplayName="About"
          Source="/View/Pages/AboutView.xaml"/>
    <mui:Link DisplayName="Settings"
          Source="/View/Pages/SettingsView.xaml"/>
    <mui:Link DisplayName="Gallery"
          Source="/View/Pages/GalleryView.xaml"/>
    </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
</mui:LinkGroup>
...
```

**Example code behind**

```
string url = "/View/Pages/AboutView.xaml";
NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
nav.Navigate(new System.Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

I like to refactor a lot, so I don't want to rely on hardcoded paths to source files. I've been thinking maybe a global dictionary-like structure that maps class types `typeof(XyzViewModel)` to their respective paths would be a neat idea (at least I'd have everything in one place), but then again, [singletons are evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil). I don't think reflection is an answer too.

Is there a way to handle this situation without resorting to anti-patterns?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many refactoring save ways to do it.

One thing you can do is use a class with constants, containing all of your paths.

```
namespace MyApp.Shared 
{
    public static class NavigationConstants
    {
        public const string About = "/View/Page/AboutView.xaml";
    }
}
```

and then use it in code behind instead of magic strings: `nav.Navigate(new System.Uri(NavigationConstants.About, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`

It's not singleton pattern and won't be in the way in terms of decoupling or unit testing.

On the XAML side you can use the `Static` keyword to map the path.

```
   xmlns:shared="clr-namespace:MyApp.Shared"
...
<mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Menu">
    <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="About"
            Source="{x:Static shared:NavigationConstants.About}"/>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Settings"
            Source="{x:Static shared:NavigationConstants.Settings}"/>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Gallery"
            Source="{x:Static shared:NavigationConstants.Gallery}"/>
    </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
</mui:LinkGroup>
```